# PHP ffmpeg conversion error

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I tried to convert some videos with ffmpeg and PHP.

When I execute the following command in PHP exec()

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/test/public_html/test.m4v -vcodec libx264 -acodec libmp3lame -r 30 -s 640x480 -b 100k /home/test/public_html/output_640x480_test.m4v
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: line 4: /var/log/ffmpeg.log: Permission denied
FFmpeg version SVN-r26402, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 18 2012 05:19:10 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/src/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora
  libavutil     50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0
  libavcore      0.16. 1 /  0.16. 1
  libavcodec    52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
  libavformat   52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3
  libavfilter    1.74. 0 /  1.74. 0
  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0

Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1200.00 (1200/1) -> 10.00 (10/1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/test/public_html/test.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4VP
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: M4VPM4V M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2013-03-14 10:08:25
    encoder         : Mac OS X v10.7.4 (CMA 891, CM 705.78, x86_64)
    date            : 2013-03-10T14:05:41+1100
  Duration: 00:00:02.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 245 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 32000 Hz, 2 channels (FC), s16, 31 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-14 10:08:25
    Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 400x226 [PAR 1:1 DAR 200:113], 216 kb/s, 10.35 fps, 10 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-14 10:08:25
[buffer @ 0xf6093c0] w:400 h:226 pixfmt:yuv420p
[scale @ 0xf609790] w:400 h:226 fmt:yuv420p -> w:640 h:480 fmt:yuv420p flags:0xa0000004
[libx264 @ 0xf605cd0] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
[libx264 @ 0xf605cd0] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
[libx264 @ 0xf605cd0] preset usage: -vpre <speed> -vpre <profile>
[libx264 @ 0xf605cd0] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
[libx264 @ 0xf605cd0] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
Output #0, ipod, to '/home/test/public_html/output_640x480_test.m4v':
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 150:113 DAR 200:113], q=2-31, 800 kb/s, 90k tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-14 10:08:25
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: libmp3lame, 32000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-14 10:08:25
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

The same conversion is working fine in another server. But not in our current server. What should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Look here: http://netheadaches.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/error-while-opening-codec-for-output-stream-01-maybe-incorrect-parameters-such-as-bit_rate-rate-width-or-height/

Comment: @RomanNewaza This isn't even closely related to the problem here. The final error message is just generic. Enn Fenn, is there any way you can update FFmpeg to a more recent version? What's the version on the other server? I'm guessing you have a few presets in `/usr/share/ffmpeg/` that simply don't work with the version of x264 you're using. In fact, these presets shouldn't be used anymore and wouldn't work if you were on a somewhat recent version of FFmpeg, so please update it and try again.

Comment: What happens when you run the command with `-vpre medium` added? (Again, this shouldn't be used, but could be a workaround for your older version.)

Comment: Hi slhck, thanks for the suggestion. I tried -vpre medium but it gives the error "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)"
I guess I need to update ffmpeg. It seems we have an obsolete version.

Comment: Yeah, that could very well be. Note that this isn't the actual error source – it's often somewhere within the output log. (Please ping other users, e.g. with `@slhck`, so they get a notification. I just happened to check this post by accident.)

Answer (score -1):

Try to reinstall ffmpeg and try again.

Install guide: http://w3tool.blogspot.in/search/label/ffmpeg